# numpy.uint(): transform float to uint gives [Totally] different results with large numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, uint

I was experimenting with `numpy.uint()` and `numpy.around()`

Here is what I have done:

```
>>> matrix = np.matrix([-32, -32.0, -3.91886975727153e-15])
>>> matrix
    matrix([[-3.20000000e+01, -3.20000000e+01, -3.91886976e-15]])
>>> np.uint(matrix)
...         
    matrix([[4294967264, 4294967264,          0]], dtype=uint32)
>>> np.around(matrix)
...                         
    matrix([[-32., -32.,  -0.]])
>>> np.uint(np.around(matrix))
...                         
    matrix([[4294967264, 4294967264,          0]], dtype=uint32)
```

---

Same happends with `np.uint8` `np.uint16` but with different values:

```
np.uint8(np.around(matrix))
matrix([[224, 224,   0]], dtype=uint8)

np.uint16(np.around(matrix))                        
matrix([[65504, 65504,     0]], dtype=uint16)
```

Why uint functions act that way?

Comment: '.... gives totally different results...': different from what? What did you expect?

Comment: Do you know the meaning of `u` in `uint`?

Comment: Converting negative values to **unsigned** integers currently cause an **undefined behaviour** in Numpy (though the value is often -1 converted to the target integer type that is typically `2**32-1` -- platform dependent). We tried as much as possible to add warning in this case but there are some rare cases where it is no message. Please check you use a recent version of Numpy and please be careful about warnings. We also assume users not to do conversion that does not make any sense (though they can happen when unexpected values are provided to such conversion functions).

Comment: @Swifty , yes, from expected result.

Now I understand the difference beetwen `int` and `uint` and why uint gives those results(which are actually predictable on my computer).
@JérômeRichard , I am using numpy 1.24.1 version, If you mean Python warning, I didnt get any.

Comment: @Qwerth "undefined behaviour" is a common term it might be worth looking it up.  it's worth figuring out what is defining the behaviour you see and whether you care about when that wouldn't apply.  specifically here it's due to popular CPUs using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integer operations